# How do I fix this error with allocation and deallocation mismatch?

Tags: c++, cppcheck

Cppcheck report as an error "Mismatching allocation and deallocation: cname" for the line with `delete cname;`. I don't see what the problem with using my version of code is - it looks working.

Is my code wrong? How do I fix it? And what are the consequences of using my code?

```
if ( lenght != 0 )
{
   char *cname = new char[lenght+1];    
   inbin.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>( cname ), lenght );
   cname[lenght] = '\0';
   *ptr_string = cname;             
   delete cname;
 }
```

Comment: Array deallocation is done via "delete [] cname"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, when you allocate an array using the `new …[…]` syntax, you should deallocate it using `delete[]`. In your case, you need `delete[] cname;`.

If you use the wrong form of `delete` to match your allocation with `new`, you have undefined behaviour:

> *§5.3.5/2 [expr.delete]* In the ﬁrst alternative (*delete object*), the value of the operand of `delete` may be a null pointer value, a pointer to a non-array object created by a previous *new-expression*, or a pointer to a subobject representing a base class of such an object. If not, the behavior is undeﬁned. In the second alternative (*delete array*), the value of the operand of `delete` may be a null pointer value or a pointer value that resulted from a previous array *new-expression*. If not, the behavior is undeﬁned.

Comment: thanks. got it. ohh... really simple. and what is about the consequences of using my version of code?

Comment: @abrahab The most terrible consequence: undefined behaviour.

Comment: @abrahab Standard quote has been added to my answer.

Comment: Basically, the delete[] variant will call the destructor of each of the array objects. In case of scalar values it might not seem important, but if you are defining an array of classes, the difference is huge.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( lenght != 0 )
    {
        char *cname = new char[lenght+1];   
        inbin.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>( cname ), lenght );
        cname[lenght] = '\0';
        *ptr_string = cname;                
        delete[] cname;
    }
```